# How to prevent child inheriting parent height without assigning height using taiwind

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I dont want child to inherit paren height and i want the child to expand according to the content in it. And dont want to assign height as well as i dont know much content will be in it.

```
<div class="flex w-full bg-red-400 p-5 h-screen">
  <div class="flex w-40 bg-yellow-400 p-5">
    Lorem ipsum is typically a corrupted version of De finibus bonorum et malorum, a 1st-century BC text by the Roman statesman and philosopher Cicero, with words altered, added, and removed to make it nonsensical and improper Latin. The first two words themselves are a truncation of dolorem
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove h-screen and add new property from tailwindcss to the second div element. overflow-auto

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow - Learn more about overflow class of tailwindcss.

```
<div class="flex w-full bg-red-400 p-5">
  <div class="flex w-40 bg-yellow-400 p-5 overflow-auto">
    Lorem ipsum is typically a corrupted version of De finibus bonorum et malorum, a 1st-century BC text by the Roman statesman and philosopher Cicero, with words altered, added, and removed to make it nonsensical and improper Latin. The first two words themselves are a truncation of dolorem
  </div>
</div>
```